# Screen occasionally won't come on

Tags: screen

I have what I believe to be a software problem with My Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.2. Occasionally the phone will turn it's display off, or I will manually trigger this with the lock button. Minutes, maybe hours later when I want to use the phone it refuses to respond to the power button. The screen will never come on with it. However, it will come on if a call comes through. Texts still vibrate the phone and flash the indicator. Holding the power to force the power off does not work, it requires removing the battery. Then it works like normal. Any ideas?

Comment: I have seen the same issue on mine. I'm afraid it's endemic to the phone. It may be related to the CPU being at 100% usage. Sometimes connecting or disconnecting the charger will kick the screen on. Removing and replacing the battery always works. But I don't think there's a real, reliable solution for us.